# How to select a sql table's column value by giving column index?

Tags: sql, indexing

I have table with 3 columns. One is `Id`, second column is `Name` and the third one `Description`. How can I select the value in the `Description` field by giving the column index, 3?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a bit confusing, are you trying to select the content in column 3?

Comment: Needing this `feels` like an symptom of another problem.  Are you able to elaborate so that we can put any potential answer in the context of your situation?  We may even be able to offer alternatives that don't require this.  Also, are you able to specify Which version of SQL you're using?

Comment: This is the most elementary SQL. You should have a look to a tutorial or curse on SQL.

Comment: Actually I would like to select the content in description field like this   "select @description=tbl_name.de.  where id=1"  I cannot give the exact table details because its under hip-pa law. Please help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help with TSQL - a way to get the value in the Nth column of a row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437117/help-with-tsql-a-way-to-get-the-value-in-the-nth-column-of-a-row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, from plain SQL (other than in the ORDER BY clause, which won't give you the value but will allow you to sort the result set by it).

If you are using another programming language to construct a dynamic query, you could use that to identify the column being selected by its index number.

Alternatively, you could parameterise your query to return a specific column based on a case statement - like so:

```
select a, b, c, d, e, ...,
       case ?
           when 1 then a
           when 2 then b
           when 3 then c
           when 4 then d
           when 5 then e
           ...
       end as parameterised_column
from ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with referring to a column by an index number is that, one day, someone may add a column and break your application as the wrong value will be returned.

This principle is enforced in SQL because you can select named columns, or all columns using the * syntax.

This principle is not enforced in programming languages, where you can usually access the column by ordinal in code, but you should consider the principle before deciding to use a statement such as (psuedo code)

```
value = results[0].column[2].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible.  You'd have to query the system tables (which do vary from one version of SQL to another) to get the 3rd (or Nth) column name as a string to form a following query using that column name.

In SQL 2000 the tables you'll need to start with are syscolumns with a join to sysobjects for the table name.  Then the rank() function on "Colid" will give you the Nth column and "name" (shockingly) the name of the column.  Once you've got that in a variable the following command can return the value, compare to it, order by it or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can retrieve a Column's name by passing it's index. 
Here variable `AcID` is used as the index of the column. 
Below is the code e.g

```
    dim gFld as string

    vSqlText1 = "Select * from RecMast where ID = 1000"
    vSql1 = New SqlClient.SqlCommand(vSqlText1, cnnRice)
    vRs1 = vSql1.ExecuteReader

    if vRs1.Read then
        gFld = vRs1.GetName(AcID)
        msgbox gfld
    end if
```

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @searchIndex int
set @searchIndex = 3
select Description from tbl_name t where t.Id = @searchIndex
```

Comment: He's not after the third row, he wants the third column.

Comment: Okay. It wasn't clear to me. I obviously confused that "description field" with Description entry on row 3